# Why is the subjunctive used in Vergil's Georgics, 3,250?

Tags: meaning, vergilius

Vergil's Georgics, book 3, line 250, [reads](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0059%3Abook%3D3%3Acard%3D242):

> nonne vides ut tota tremor **pertemptet** equorum corpora si tantum notas odor attulit auras.

Why is the subjunctive mood used here? And what is this *ut*?

Comment: Good question, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 8):

It's an indirect question following the interrogative *ut*, which takes the subjunctive:

> Surely you see *how*...

For *ut* used in this way, see its [Lewis & Short entry](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dut).

Comment: but ut is not an interrogative. its about fear, purpose. how is like that in english. wheres that in a latin dic?

Comment: @user21669 That is incorrect. Look at the [very first definitions](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dut) in Lewis & Short.

Comment: how is used like that right in english. like i understand how life is tough. so the same thing is happening in latin?

Comment: this ut is used like "that". you see that horses are....?

Comment: @user21669 Precisely like the English there. In Latin, a *that* like "you see that horses are" would be indirect statement, so accusative + infinitive: *vides equos esse..."